# How to do language model training on BERT

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to train BERT on a target corpus. I am looking at this [HuggingFace implementation](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling#robertabertdistilbert-and-masked-language-modeling).
They are using .raw files for the training data. If I have .txt files of my training data, how can I use their implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.raw` only indicates that they use the raw version of the WikiText, they are regular text files containing the raw text:

> We're using the raw WikiText-2 (no tokens were replaced before the tokenization).

The description of the data files options also says that they are text files. From [run_language_modeling.py - L86-L88](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/5e737018e1fcb22c8b76052058279552a8d6c806/examples/language-modeling/run_language_modeling.py#L86-L88):

```py
train_data_file: Optional[str] = field(
    default=None, metadata={"help": "The input training data file (a text file)."}
)
```

Therefore you can just specify your text files.

Comment: Do you know the formatting of the text files? The old version was one sentence per line and one empty line between separate documents. Is it the same here?

Comment: I don't think the LMs have ever used that format, that's for other tasks. It looks like you have two possibilities, [see `get_dataset`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/5e737018e1fcb22c8b76052058279552a8d6c806/examples/language-modeling/run_language_modeling.py#L118-L125), either the text is continuous and split into equal sized chunks, or you can have one sequence per line by setting the [`--line_by_line`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/5e737018e1fcb22c8b76052058279552a8d6c806/examples/language-modeling/run_language_modeling.py#L93-L96) flag.

Comment: Oh I see. Just to check, if my main objective is to get sentence embeddings from a pre-trained BERT model that is further trained on unlabeled text from a target corpus, is this the best method? Also when you say sequence, does that mean sentence or group of sentences/document?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the best option to fine tune with unlabelled text. Sequence would be a sentence in this case, I just say sequence, because it doesn't have to be a single full sentence (could be part of it, or two sentences that you want to keep together).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help. So there is no distinctions between documents then? Would that affect the training? Or would it not matter much since those divisions occur less frequently than the divisions between the continuous sentences?

Comment: There is no notion of documents in the language model. It shouldn't really matter for the training.